# Helper Attribute of Procedural Macro not found

Tags: rust

A rust project that did compile once (a while ago) suddenly gives some macro-related error.

I have a custom procedural macro (using *proc_macro2* ):

```
#[proc_macro_derive(Parsable, attributes(AllocLifetime, ByteSize, Transient, VirtualSize, StartIndex))]
pub fn parse_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
 ...
}
```

Here is a simple usage (only using the *AllocLifetime* which is involved in the error):

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Parsable, Serializable, VirtualSize)]
pub struct Exp<#[AllocLifetime] 'b>(pub SlicePtr<'b, OpCode<'b>>);
```

I get the following error during compilation:

```
error: cannot find attribute `AllocLifetime` in this scope
   --> ...
    |
127 | pub enum RuntimeType<#[AllocLifetime] 'a> {
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

*Parsable*, *Serializable*, and *VirtualSize* are my custom procedural macros but *Parsable* uses *AllocLifetime* the others do not, that's why I only provided the signature of *Parsable*. Further, *parse_derive* successfully runs for *RuntimeType* and see/uses *AllocLifetime* to do its thing, the error appears after the macro is executed.

What could have changed that led to this error and what do I need to change to fix it?

Comment: If something stopped working after you updated Rust, this is probably a bug you need to report. Find the last version of Rust this worked in.

Comment: If you have more time, you can also find the exact PR that caused the bug using [cargo-bisect-rustc](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo-bisect-rustc/). Don't worry if you don't: others will do that if you fill an issue.